# Getting a 'this' reference to a 2nd level prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible, but wanted to see if anyone had some ingenious ideas as to how to make it possible.

I want the following code to work:

```
var x = new foo();
x.a.getThis() === x; // true
```

In other words, I want `x.a.getThis` to have a reference to `this` being `x` in this case.  Make sense?

In order to get this to work ***one*** level deep is simple:

```
function foo(){}
foo.prototype.getThis = function(){ return this; }
var x = new foo();
x.getThis() === x; // true
```

One thing, I want this to work as a prototype, no "cheating" by manually binding to `this`:

```
function foo(){
    this.a = {
        getThis : (function(){ return this; }).bind(this)
    };
}
```

Although the above is a perfect functional example of what I'm trying to achieve, I just don't want all the extra functions for each instance :)

FYI, the actual use case here is that I'm creating classes to represent Cassandra objects in node and I want to be able to reference a super-column --> column-family --> column via `foo.a.b` and keep a reference to `foo` in the deep function.

Comment: You mean you want `Function.prototype.getThis = function(){}`?

Comment: no, I want `getThis` to have it's `this` reference pointing at the object 2 levels up, in this case `x`.  I'll modify the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: `var that = this; this.a = { getThis : function() { return that } };` no good?

Comment: @alex - I don't want to recursively re-define a bunch of functions in the constructor for both code-cleanliness and performance reasons.  I'd actually end up re-defining and wrapping a good 70-100 functions if I did that, thus 70-100 extra closures on each instance of the class created.  I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work while keeping the function references in the prototype so that I'm not creating thousands of new functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without a forced bind of some kind.  You say you don't want to "cheat" but this breaks the standard rules about what `this` is, so you have to cheat.  But JS lets you cheat, so it's all good.

BTW, for what it's worth coffee script makes this so trivial.

```
foo = ->
  @a = getThis: => this
```

The fat arrow `=>` preserves the context of this for from the scope it was called in.  This allows you to easily forward the context to another level.

That code gets compiled to this JS:

```
var foo;
var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
foo = function() {
  return this.a = {
    getThis: __bind(function() {
      return this;
    }, this)
  };
};
```

Which basically just does what you say you do not want to do.

---

Or if the value doesn't have to `this` specifically, you can set the "owner" in the child object.

```
var A = function(owner) {
  this.owner = owner;
};
A.prototype.getThis = function() {
  return this.owner;
};
var Foo = function() {
  this.a = new A(this);
};

var foo = new Foo();

if (foo.a.getThis() === foo) {
    alert('Happy dance');
} else {
    window.location = 'https://commons.lbl.gov/download/attachments/73468687/sadpanda.png';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GQPa/

And the coffee script version of that because I am a passionate and unreasonable zealot for it:

```
class A
  constructor: (@owner) ->
  getThis: -> @owner

class Foo
  constructor: -> @a = new A(this)

foo = new Foo()
if foo.a.getThis() is foo
  alert 'Happy Dance'
else
  window.location = 'https://commons.lbl.gov/download/attachments/73468687/sadpanda.png'
```

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to figure out how to not wrap ___every___ single function, which I think I just did :)  Writing a test-case now

Comment: Is it important that the object you want be `this` or can it be some other local variable shared through closure?

Comment: It can be whatever, which is what I just realized (your question makes me think we may have the same solution here, but I'd be curious to see what you're thinking), I just don't want to wrap every function prototype

Comment: Thanks, that's such a straight-forward solution :)  I just posted my own, FYI, not sure which I'll go with but yours is definitely helpful!

Comment: can you add this image to your answer?  https://commons.lbl.gov/download/attachments/73468687/sadpanda.png  It would make it epic :P

Comment: Done! But lastly, I would just make sure the anonymous functions are really a performance issue first.  Most modern JS engines can handle short simple function being created all the time no problem.  So I only ask that you make sure you are actually gaining enough performance at the cost of elegance to be worth it.  Do some bench marking.

Comment: Oh, I know it's not worth that much since each wrapped function only has the overhead of a new empty object (`{}`) and a pointer, at least in node (where this is being used) since functions compilations are cached.  But the point is that I have 81 prototyped functions on this class and I didn't wat to clone 81 functions since that's just messy.  This is also part of a caching Cassandra ORM, so there may be literally 10,000 instances of this class created so I'm trying to save the overhead of nearly 1 million extra functions

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to do reliably without binding the value at the start since the value of a function's *this* is set by the call. You can't know beforehand how it will be called, or which functions need a special or restricted call to "preserve" the *this -> this* relationship.

The function or caller's `this` may be any object, there may not be a *this -> this* at all. Consider:

```
var x = {
  a : {
    b: function() {return this;}
  }
}
```

When you call `x.a.b()`, then b's `this` is a. But if you do:

```
var c = x.a.b;
c(); // *this* is the global object
```

or

```
x.a.b.call(someOtherObject);
```

What is the value of *this -> this* in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because someone else may find it useful.  Not sure if I'll end up going with this or Squeegy's solution.  The functions are only ever defined once and then the containing object is cloned and has `parent = this` injected into it:

```
function foo(){
    var self = this, nest = this.__nestedObjects__ || [];

    nest.forEach(function(prop){
        self[prop] = extend({ parent : self }, self[prop]);
    });
}

// bound like this so that they're immutable
Object.defineProperties(foo.prototype, {
    bar : {
        enumerable : true,
        value : {
            foobar : function(){
                return this.parent;
            },
            foo : function(){},
            bar : function(){}
        }
    },
    __nestedObjects__ : { value : ['bar'] }
});

var fooInst = new foo();
console.log(fooInst.bar.foobar() == fooInst);
```

---

or based on Squeegy's solution:

```
function foo(){
    for(var cls in this.__inherit__){
        if(!this.__inherit__.hasOwnProperty(cls)){ continue; }

        this[cls] = new (this.__inherit__[cls])(this);
    }
}

var clsA;
// bound like this so that they're immutable
Object.defineProperties(foo.prototype, {
    __inherit__ : { value : {
        bar : clsA = function(parent){
                Object.defineProperty(this, '__parent__', { value : parent });
            }
        }
    }
});

clsA.prototype = {
    foobar : function(){
        return this.__parent__;
    }
};

var fooInst = new foo();
console.log(fooInst.bar.foobar() == fooInst);
```